# What's wrong with hats, i.e. $\hat \beta$?

Tags: bug, math-display

Why are the hats in $\hat \beta$ off centered?

Comment: Any chance you're using Safari?

Comment: Like that? https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/mathjax-shifted-frames

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: yes! And using Firefox fixes it. Why is that?

Comment: See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3207/mathjax-accents-in-safari-10-1#3207 and https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1737 as well as https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709. It's a change in recent Safari versions that's causing issues.

Comment: someone (either peter or cliff, probably) should write an answer, I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed by Peter and amoeba, there is an issue with Safari 10.1.

This question has come up on other stackexchange sites, see

https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3207/mathjax-accents-in-safari-10-1#3207
https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/mathjax-shifted-frames

---

Update by @amoeba, Aug 8: This seems to be resolved, both github issues mentioned above appear to be resolved and are closed.

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709
https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1737

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved (I made an update), you might want to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

Looks okay to me...

[image: image of beta-hats in Q]
maybe the MathJax rendering doesn't finish loading on your machine for some reason. Mine show as off-center for a brief moment before they look like this.

Comment: As pointed out by @PeterKrautzberger, it's an issue with Safari